# Payment Gateway for the companies registered in oman

Tags: payment-gateway

is there any payment gateway for a company that was registered in Oman? I've tried a lot. but unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal,
CashU,
Skrill,
Innovate Payments,
2CheckOut,
Cashi,
ZazPay 
are some of the popular payment gateway providers in Oman.